# logging into facebook through selenium in javascript

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write a test script that will login to facebook, but it falls short of clicking the login button.  Where did I go wrong here?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class GoogleRobotSearch {
 private Selenium sel;

 public GoogleRobotSearch () {
  sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com");
  sel.start();
 }

 public void search() {
  sel.open("http://www.facebook.com");
  sel.type("id=email","email");
  sel.type("id=pass","password");
  //sel.waitForPageToLoad("5000");
    sel.click("//input[@value='Log In']");
 }

 public static void main (String args[]) {
  GoogleRobotSearch xybot = new GoogleRobotSearch ();
  xybot.search();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webDriver we can do it like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("mail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("pwd");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For chrome driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("mail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("pwd");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
   }
```

First make sure you have chrome driver with environment variable path. If you don't have, go to http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list. Download and set path. Use this for set path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```